# Having trouble with this code. Discord purge command in js

Tags: javascript, discord

I've been working on a Discord bot as a little experiment (since I'm new to coding). It turns out I'm having problem with this code:

```
  // delete from 2-100.

  const deleteCount = parseInt(args[0], 10);

  if(!deleteCount){ 
    return message.reply("Un numero del 2-100"); //"a number from 2-100"
  }

  const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: deleteCount});
  message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
    .catch(error => message.reply(`Error: ${error}`)) }
```

This code does work: it purges the said amount of messages and sends the "Input a number from 2-100" message when only !purge or !clear is given. However, the message... it's also sent when I type the command !say, or after the bot kicks someone and sends the successfully kicked user message. It's even sent when !shop or !f are given (which aren't part of any of it's code).

How can I make the bot send the "Un numero del 2-100" **only** when the command is given without a value?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an if-statement to check if the message is the command so you can let this code execute only if it is the command.
E.g: `if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'purge') || msg.startsWith(prefix + 'clear') {}`

From what I see, all this code gets executed regardless of the command specified, which is why that string is being output regardless of the command being called.

Comment: I tried this but it just ended with the command being inoperative

Comment: If its possible, can you send the code so I can see why it is inoperative?